# How can I parse an unqualified JSON array using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

So, I am accessing a third-party API and it's giving me this JSON object, but I'm having a whale of a time trying to find an elegant way to parse the resources sub-object using Jackson.

I'm assuming I have to write a custom deserializer, though I'm wondering if there's another way...

```
{
    "somekey": "somevalue",
    "resources": [
        "list",
        [
            {
                "@type": "com.yada.Yada",
                "resource": {
                    "@type": "ServiceObjectReference",
                    "id": "emp1234",
                    "displayName": "Bob Smith"
                },
                "type": "TYPE_PERSON",
                "resourceType": 200
            },
           {
                "@type": "com.yada.Yada",
                "resource": {
                    "@type": "ServiceObjectReference",
                    "id": "emp1235",
                    "displayName": "Sue Smith"
                },
                "type": "TYPE_PERSON",
                "resourceType": 200
            }
       ]
   ]
}
```

Comment: You have unbalanced open brackets; hopefully that's not present in the JSON... ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't want to send the whole JSON message, so I did a hasty cut-and-paste job. It's syntactically correct now.

Comment: Show us how your having problems and what you tried. With Jackson bean annotions this is pretty simple.

Comment: What I've done thus far is create POJO's that map to key/value pairs. I created a class which contains a String to hold the value of "somekey" and another object to hold "resources", but if you look closely, you'll see that the first item in the resources array is a string and the second one is another array which lacks a key.

I'm trying to figure out how to get at these values. Jackson doesn't know how to handle it... and I'm at a loss to see how I can access these values without using a custom deserializer that performs a .get() on individual nodes.

What am I missing?

Comment: I created a custom deserializer for now, but am hoping there's a more elegant solution that I'm unaware of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value of resources is an array with different object type, probably you don't want to use POJO for the mapping. Not sure about your implementation of custom deserializer, but you might want to use ObjectMapper#readTree method, than read the node value based on its type

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(your_json_input);

JsnoNode resourcesNode = rootNode.path("resources");

for (JsonNode resourceNode : resourcesNode ) {
    if (resourceNode.isObject()) {
        // the node is an object, you could do POJO mapping now or keep using path() method to go deeper
    } else {
        // simply get the String value
        String list = resourceNode.getTextValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: My custom deserializer does something along these lines. It iterates through the contents of the "resources" node, if it encounters an array object, I attempt to map its contents to a POJO. Everything else (i.e. the "list"object) is ignored.

Whoever came up with this syntax as part of the messages coming back from the Rest API i'm querying needs to be beaten with the rubber hose. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the producer of the json uses polymorphic type handling.
We can all agree that this is not something to use in a public api.

However, you could try to annotate your classes so that jackson can make use of this though.

The annotation @JsonTypeInfo would be your starting point

It would look something like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyYada.class, name="com.yada.Yada")
})
public class MyYada
```

Comment: Yes, I have implemented classes to handle the type mapping. That's a piece of cake. It looks like whoever wrote these API's didn't understand the bag of hurt they caused by failing to remain consistent in terms of creating keys for all objects.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and it looks like this is a "2-element JSON array". It can be parsed using JsonTypeInfo.As(WRAPPER_ARRAY)

http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonTypeInfo.As.html#WRAPPER_ARRAY