# Polymorphic Jackson deserialization: getting either a string or an array of strings

Tags: java, json, jackson

My question is pretty much identical to this one, except that I'm using Java/Jackson instead of C#:

[In C# how can I deserialize this json when one field might be a string or an array of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141610/in-c-sharp-how-can-i-deserialize-this-json-when-one-field-might-be-a-string-or-a)

My input JSON can be this:

```
{ "foo": "a string" }
```

or this:

```
{ "foo": ["array", "of", "strings" ] }
```

My class looks like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public List<String> foo;
}
```

If the input contains a single string, I want it to become the first entry in the list.

How can I deserialize foo using Jackson? I could write a custom deserializer, which I've done before, but I thought there might be an easier way.

Comment: The question is similar to [How can I parse an unqualified JSON array using Jackson?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684742/how-can-i-parse-an-unqualified-json-array-using-jackson).

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 6):

There is a feature called [ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Feature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) which is turned off by default but you can turn it on:

```
objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

You can also turn it on per case:

```
class SomeClass {

  @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
  private List<String> items;
  // ...
}
```